# slick slider asNavFor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a this code

```
        var toplamSlide = $(".glly_detail .glly_detail_option").length + 1;
        for (var i = 1; i < toplamSlide; i++) {
            $('.glly_detail_numbers').append('<div class="slick-item"><span>' + i + ' </span></div>');
        }

        $(".glly_detail").slick({
            nextArrow: ".btn_slick_next",
            prevArrow: ".btn_slick_prev",
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            dots: false,
            speed: 0,
            swipe: false,
            asNavFor: '.glly_detail_numbers',
        });
        $('.glly_detail_numbers').slick({
            slidesToShow: 10,
            slidesToScroll: 10,
            asNavFor: '.glly_detail',
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            swipe: false,
            //mobileFirst: false,
            focusOnSelect: true,
            responsive: [{
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 6
                    }
                }

            ]
        });
```

I want to change `glly_detail` when I click numbers of `glly_detail_numbers` slider so I added `asNavFor:".glly_detail"` to script. But I don't want to change `glly_detail` when I click of `glly_detail_numbers` slider arrow. Can it possible?

But I don't want to change glly_detail just when I click of glly_detail_numbers slider arrow (in red border). but if I click numbers of glly_detail_numbers slider, glly_detail slider must change.

if I remove asNavFor: '.glly_detail_numbers', it doesn't change. or if i remove asNavFor: '.glly_detail', it doesn't change. but I don't want this.

I don't want to change glly_detail just when I click of glly_detail_numbers slider arrow (in red border).

Can it possible?

http://project.ajanstr.com.tr/ailem/slick-slider.jpg

Comment: Try to remove `asNavFor: '.glly_detail_numbers',`? I'm not sure if I understand you correct. Do you have any visual representation?

Comment: But I don't want to change glly_detail just when I click of glly_detail_numbers slider arrow (in red border). but if I click numbers of glly_detail_numbers slider, glly_detail slider must change.

if I remove asNavFor: '.glly_detail_numbers', it doesn't change. or if i remove asNavFor: '.glly_detail', it doesn't change. but I don't want this.

I don't want to change glly_detail just when I click of glly_detail_numbers slider arrow (in red border).

Can it possible?

http://project.ajanstr.com.tr/ailem/slick-slider.jpg